# Dismissing initial ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3

I am developing an app using swift 3 . I launch a tutorial like view controller on the first launch of my app and close it using a button .But the inital view controller does not get dismissed even when i click the close button. I know the question sounds familiar but i am unable to get a correct solution for it .

Here's the code of the the AppDelegate

```
import UserNotifications
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: 
UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [ 
UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{

let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")

            if launchedBefore {
                print("This is not the first Launch")
            } else
               {
                print("First Launch, setting UserDefaults")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                let initiaView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstLaunchViewController")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initiaView
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


            }
    return true
}
```

Here's my code from the initialViewController

```
  class FirstLaunchViewController:UIViewController
  {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
     }

    @IBAction func doneButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) 
    {
      _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
    }
 }
```

Comment: it will be dissmiss while you have pushed that controller. here you have set as rootViewController so you can't pop .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController // this is your initial viewcontroller set initial viewcontroller in storyboard
let initiaView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstLaunchViewController")
 rootViewController.pushViewController(initiaView, animated: true)
```

Comment: thank you :) but when i  do this ` let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController // this is your initial viewcontroller set initial viewcontroller in storyboard`  it does not take the initial view controller as an argument

Comment: yes it displays "Value of type UIWindow has no member InitialViewController " (Here InitialViewController is the view i set as initial view in storyboard)

Comment: Then you need select initial viewcontroller in storyboard...open storyboard -> select any view controller and check it as initial viewcontroller

Comment: thank you :) My fault was i never considered the fact that i was using navogationController in my storyboard

Comment: yes so i set the navigationController as the rootView controller and then push from rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the view controller as root view controller for window which you want to show after dismissing the initial view controller. Present the initial view controller from window root view controller